# Serving video from Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

what is the correct way to serve videos through Asp.net to HTML5 video player? The way I know is specifying the path directly in the src attribute, but how can I specify a src like host/Controller/GetVideo/identifier that would work the same way as specifying the file path directly? What should I return on the action method on Asp?

Comment: you get file path on drive/db by id and then stream the bytes to the output. make sure you stream buffered response e.g. 1mb at the time otherwise you can run out of memory if you'll load the whole file in ram

Comment: What file type would the action have to return? And would that work just like specifying the path in html5?

Comment: Action would be `ActionResult` I guess, it depends on your version of MVC. And yes, the html would be the same, it would be something like `/videos/87` where `87` is the id of video.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a controller action that returns FileStreamResult.

You can have a Videos Controller, inside the controller, create an Index action or get action that takes the name of the video, in the view you can get the video using;

/Videos/ALM

Comment: So I'm suppones to return a FileStreamResult object? How can I make sure that many users can access de same video at the same time without problems?

Comment: Media should be served by something built for that purpose, I encourage you to have a look at Azure media service